# Scanner Barcode Qr in Webview?

Tags: android, webview, barcode

I would like create a app that use Scanner Barcode QR in Webview of Android. It's posible?

I've been looking around here and found nothing related to this topic :(

Thanks all!

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8009309/2617699

Answer (score 1):

QR Code require Camera access to capture photo and process QR Code, Web / HTML can't access hardware of mobile, so It's not possible to create such application, but there are two possible workaround

1. Create QR Scanning module in Native Android and use JavaScript Interface to bridge between your web and native, For more detail please visit following link
   http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/overview.html
2. As "Webaldo.at" suggest, detect html element when user click in web view and open any 3rd party QR Scanner app